# REGEX mistake in java

Tags: java, regex

I have two line that are as the same but they have two different results!

```
public static String data =
                "Rome:Jan 81.2,Feb 63.2,Mar 70.3,Apr 55.7,May 53.0,Jun 36.4,Jul 17.5,Aug 27.5,Sep 60.9,Oct 117.7,Nov 111.0,Dec 97.9" +
                "\n" +
                "London:Jan 48.0,Feb 38.9,Mar 39.9,Apr 42.2,May 47.3,Jun 52.1,Jul 59.5,Aug 57.2,Sep 55.4,Oct 62.0,Nov 59.0,Dec 52.9" +
                "\n";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mean("London", data));
}

public static double mean(String town, String strng) {
    Matcher matched=checkExists(town + "(.*?)\n", data);
    if (matched!=null)
        return calAvr(matched.group(1)+",");
    return -1;
}

private static Matcher checkExists(String regex, String source) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(source);
    if (matcher.find()) return matcher;
    return null;
}

private static double calAvr(String splitData) {
    double res = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    //Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s(.*?),").matcher(splitData);
    Matcher matcher=checkExists("\\s(.*?),", splitData);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        res += Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
        count++;
    }
    return res / count;
}
```

These two line are as the same:

```
//Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s(.*?),").matcher(splitData);
Matcher matcher=checkExists("\\s(.*?),", splitData);
```

When I use the first one it find all the numbers.In second one I just return the matcher object and use it but it could not find "48.0" which is the first occurrence! I have used the matcher object in mean func and that works fine!

Comment: Would you be able to post a single java file that executes both lines (that are the same) and compares the different outputs?

Comment: you are getting each number in first line as i m trying to run the code `81.2` is not coming with your regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call
`Matcher matcher=checkExists("\\s(.*?),", splitData);`
you are executing `find()` for the first time, and then 
you use `while (matcher.find())` which means than you just have lost the first match cause you are executing `find` after the first `find` without dealing with data.

This does not happen, however, when you use `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s(.*?),").matcher(splitData);` instead...

see documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())

> public boolean find() Attempts to find the next subsequence of the
>   input sequence that matches the pattern. This method starts at the
>   beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of
>   the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, **at
>   the first character not matched by the previous match.**
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.